# Index was outside the bounds of the array [VB.NET]

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vb.net-2010

Hi i am new to VB and in the process of learning. This error occur sometimes and doesn't occur sometimes which i find it weird.
I receive the error `Index was outside the bounds of the array`, that points to `Button30.Text = Split(newestversion, vbCrLf)(**1**)`

My motive is to read line by line from a online hosted text file.
For example,

```
label1.text = line 1 of the text file
label2.text = line 2 of the text file
```

This is very much what i want.

Here is my current code (EDITED):

```
Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("direct link to my online txt file")
Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse

Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream)

Dim stringReader As String

        stringReader = sr.ReadLine()
        Button10.Text = stringReader


        Dim newestversion As String = sr.ReadToEnd
        Dim currentversion As String = Application.ProductVersion

        Dim part() As String = Split(newestversion, vbCrLf)

        If part.Length < 10 Then
            ' not enough items in the array. You could also throw and exception or do some other stuff here
            Label10.Text = "beta"
            Exit Sub
        End If


        'updates new episode numbers on buttons
        Button20.Text = part(0)
        Button30.Text = part(1)
        Button40.Text = part(2)
        Button50.Text = part(3)
        Button60.Text = part(4)
        Button70.Text = part(5)
        Button80.Text = part(6)
        Button90.Text = part(7)
        Button100.Text = part(8)
        Button110.Text = part(9)

    End If
```

Thank You!!

Comment: As the error suggests, your `newestversion` variable does not consist of enough lines.

Comment: Use System.IO.File.ReadAllLines() instead.  An pay attention to the Length property of the returned array, if it is too low then you know that the file contained garbage.

Answer (score 1):

You split your `String` for `line breaks`. This gives you an array, having one entry for each line in the `String`. However, you do not check if this array holds the amount of items you expect. You could do:

```
Dim newestversion As String = sr.ReadToEnd
Dim currentversion As String = Application.ProductVersion

Dim part() As String = Split(newestversion, vbCrLf)

If part.Length < 10 Then
    ' not enough items in the array. You could also throw and exception or do some other stuff here
    MsgBox(String.Format("Array only has {0} items", part.Length))
    Exit Sub 
End If

'updates new episode numbers on buttons
Button20.Text = part(0)
Button30.Text = part(1)
Button40.Text = part(2)
...
```

### Edit for the updated question

If you do have a problem like this, just approach it systematically and get as much information as you can. First you have to check if you really get the data you want from the remote source. To do that, add some logging (e.g. a `MsgBox(newestversion)` or a real log file). **Check if the data you get is what you expect**. If not, there's already a problem with your request/response code, which is a completely different problem than what I provided a solution for. If `newestversion` is OK, check if the splitting works by printing out the `part()` array. Maybe the server uses a different operating system or just uses `vbCr` as newline and not `vbCrlf`. If the splitting also works, you are done.

Comment: it didn't work. It didn't read and change the text of the buttons

Comment: The easiest way to check what is happening is to set a `breakpoint` somewhere and step through the process. One of the following has to happen: an exception is thrown somewhere `OR` you see the message box and then the method exits `OR` the buttons have the text you want them to have. If you don't want to debug, I would advice you log the content of `newestversion` (to a file, to the console or with a message box).

Comment: there isn't any error. The code above you gave shows no error and it doesn't retrieve data from the text file ):

Comment: Well, you have to put it at the right place in your code of course. The line `Dim newestversion As String = sr.ReadToEnd` also exists in the code you posted above. Just paste the code I gave you to that position. Just to clarify again: you need to use the code YOU posted and put the snipped I provided into that code. You might have noticed that I also use `sr.ReadToEnd`. This `sr` instance is the one you declared in the code of your question.

Comment: yep i think i did let me edit my post with the new edit

Comment: Edited sir. Please help ):

Comment: i checked and didn't get what i want. All buttons text remains as default. Part array also did not show anything.

Comment: I'm sorry but the amount of information you provide is simply to low to help you further. Check if you get the right file from the server and figure out which line exactly is not doing what you want it to do. Easiest way is **debugging** your application.